# Laravel/Algolia - `php artisan scout:import "App\item" ` not updating attributes in Algolia

Tags: php, laravel, search, algolia, laravel-scout

I'm struggling to figure out why this inst working, I've added some columns to my SQL database, and wish to update my algolia index with the changes. 
I'm running the command in question in the cmd, and it says imported successfully into algolia, however when I check my algolia dashboard the index attributes have not been updated. Additionally,, if I use `php artisan scout:flush "App\item"` (which is my model/index), the entries for the index in algolia are not cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Soln => My SearchableAs() function in my model was returning the wrong index name, changed it to return the correct algolia index name, and re-ran the commands and it worked.